# How to know my sudo password?

Tags: software-installation, login, password, sudo, skype

I am really new to Ubuntu. I had it installed without me knowing what were the username or password. Now, I am trying to install skype, but ask me for authentication. I have read instructions on how to until I read this `sudo`. I follow commands but it ask me for password. How would I know what my password is?

Comment: It is usually the same password that you used to log-in to ubuntu